# How to achieve two way data binding to display the data that is stored in local storage on an input filed in Html?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I have fetched all the data from an sign up API, I want the respective fields in a page to be allocated with the the data of sign up page as default
 (First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone Number). Would be most appreciated if anyone could assist me with this. Below are my html, component.ts and services.ts codes.

---

```
    **accountinfo.component.html**

    <div class="card card-blur">
      <div class="card-header">
        <p>ACCOUNT INFORMATION</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Profile Image</p>
                <img src="/assets/icon/student.svg" style="width:80%">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <ul style="margin-top:20px;">
                  <ul style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <li>Take picture of id from your phone or mobile camera</li>

                  </ul>
                </ul>

              </div>
          </div>
     <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
        <fieldset>
        <div class="row form-inline">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
            <input ngModel name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
          </div>
          </div>

              <input type="email" class="form-control" ngModel name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" (keypress)="onlyNumberKey($event)" ngModel name="PhoneNumber" id="pnumber" placeholder="Phone Number"minlength="10" maxlength="10">
            </div>

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accountInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails'));
    console.log(this.accountInfo.CandidateID);

  }

  submit() {

    var updateProfile = {

      ProfilePic:"Photo",
    }
    console.log(updateProfile);
    this.acinfo.accountDetails(updateProfile).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show the console data ?

Comment: I have added the console of my Signup page sir.

Comment: try out answer and let me know if you have difficulty in understanding concept

Comment: Hi Bharath. Please do not vandalize your posts. Your edit invalidates the answer provided below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` for two way binding.

I will take example of first name to bind.

In HTML : `<input [(ngModel)]="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">`

Define in class : `FirstName:string`

After you got values : `this.FirstName = this.accountInfo.FirstName`

and work is done! I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Template driven form` approach you need to make use of banana syntax `[(ngModel)]="propertyname"`

so your code should be like this where you want to perform bind with your input controls

```
  <input [(ngModel)]= " this.accountInfo && this.accountInfo.FirstName" 
    name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
```

Read more here : [Two-way binding ( [(...)] )](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)

Answer (score 0):

I am rewriting the whole code, just in case you're curious

```
<div class="card card-blur">
  <div class="card-header">
    <p>ACCOUNT INFORMATION</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Profile Image</p>
            <img src="/assets/icon/student.svg" style="width:80%">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <ul style="margin-top:20px;">
              <ul style="margin-top:20px;">
                <li>Take picture of id from your phone or mobile camera</li>

              </ul>
            </ul>

          </div>
      </div>
 <form #f="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
    <fieldset>
    <div class="row form-inline">
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <input [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="lastName" name="LastName" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <br/>
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="email">Email </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="emailID" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" (keypress)="onlyNumberKey($event)" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" id="pnumber" placeholder="Phone Number"minlength="10" maxlength="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="tzone">Time Zone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <select class="form-control" id="tzone" [(ngModel)]="timeZone" name="TimeZone" >
          <option ngValue="1">1</option>
          <option ngValue="2">2</option>
          <option ngValue="3">3</option>
          <option ngValue="4">4</option>
          <option ngValue="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:5em">Update</button>
  </form>

</div>
<!-- {{f.value | json}} -->
</div>
```

And for ts:

```
accountinfo.component.ts

import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { accountInfo } from './accountinfo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accountinfo',
  templateUrl: './accountinfo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accountinfo.component.scss']
})
export class AccountinfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("f")
  form: NgForm;
  accountInfo;

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient, private acinfo: accountInfo) { }

  onlyNumberKey(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // returns number from keyboard
    if (event.charCode !== undefined) {
      return event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0
        ? null
        : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57;
    } else {
      return event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 0
        ? null
        : event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstName="";
    this.lastName="";
    this.emailID = "";
    this.contactNumber = "";
    this.timeZone = "";
    this.accountInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails'));
    console.log(this.accountInfo.CandidateID);

  }

  submit() {

    var updateProfile = {

      CandidateID:this.accountInfo.CandidateID,
      this.firstName:this.form.value.FirstName,
      this.lastName:this.form.value.LastName,
      BirthDate:"07/11/1995",
      this.contactNumber:"2798349038",
      this.emailID: this.form.value.Email,
      this.timeZone:"1",
      UniversityName:"VTU",
      Campus:"Ftu",
      ProfilePic:"Photo",
      LatLon:"1231",
      IPAddress:"122323",
      Country:"Country",
      State:"State",
      City:"City",
      ContactISDCode:"91",
      CountryCode:"IN",
      IsDesktop:"true",
    }
    console.log(updateProfile);
    this.acinfo.accountDetails(updateProfile).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

This will take all required values stored in local storage and will display the data on your webpage.

Hope it Help.

Comment: Thanks you sir for your detailed solution it helped me a lot.